# Schwarz Inequality Proof: The Mystery of the Disappearing Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I've been scratching my head over this for about 45 minutes now, and I have no idea where why the $w$ in this proof disappeared.

$\left| \left \langle u,v \right \rangle \right| \le \|u\| \|v\| $

We have an orthogonal decomposition $u = \frac{\left \langle u , v \right \rangle }{\|v\|^2 }v+ w $ where $w$ is orthogonal to $v$. The Pythagorean theorem states:

$$\|u\|^2 = \left\|\ \frac{\left \langle u , v \right \rangle }{\|v\|^2 }v \right\| ^2 + \|\ w \|\ ^2 $$

Next we take the square root on and multiply by $\|v\|^2$ and we are left with the inequality we wanted to prove. Where did the $w$ go?!

Comment: That's a rather slick proof.  But why are you worried about the missing $\|w\|$?  It is just a non-negative quantity, and when it disappears it just makes the equality into an inequality.

Comment: $\sqrt{a}\le\sqrt{a+b}$ when $a,b\ge0$

Comment: Wow, I'm shocked that I didn't see that...

This proof is from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. I thought it was a pretty proof too, I've seen others that are not so pleasing to the eyes.